# How to use a custom scoring function in GridSearchCV for unsupervised learning

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, grid-search

I want to grid search over a set of hyper parameters to tune a clustering model. `GridSearchCV` offers a bunch of scoring functions for unsupervised learning but I want to use a function that's not in there, e.g. [silhouette score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)).

The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#implementing-your-own-scoring-object) on how to implement my custom function is unclear on how we should define our scoring function. The example there shows simply importing a custom scorer and using `make_scorer` to create a custom scoring function. However, `make_scorer` seems to require the true values (which doesn't exist in unsupervised learning), so it's not clear how to use it.

Here's what I have so far:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score, make_scorer

def my_custom_function(model, X):
    preds = model.predict(X)
    return silhouette_score(X, preds)

Z, _ = make_blobs()

model = DBSCAN()
pgrid = {'eps': [0.1*i for i in range(1,6)]}
gs = GridSearchCV(model, pgrid, scoring=my_custom_function)
gs.fit(Z)
best_score = gs.score(Z)
```

But it throws two errors:

```
TypeError: my_custom_function() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

and

```
AttributeError: 'DBSCAN' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

How do I correctly define my custom scoring function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `predict` method but you can make a custom one.

One approach is to iterate through the core points and assign your new point to the cluster of the first core point that falls within a specified margin, denoted as 'eps.' This ensures that your point will, at the very least, be classified as a border point for the cluster it's assigned to, based on the clustering definitions in use.

```
import scipy as sp, numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score, make_scorer

def dbscan_predict(dbscan_model, X_new, metric=sp.spatial.distance.cosine):
    # Result is noise by default
    y_new = np.ones(shape=len(X_new), dtype=int)*-1 

    # Iterate all input samples for a label
    for j, x_new in enumerate(X_new):
        # Find a core sample closer than EPS
        for i, x_core in enumerate(dbscan_model.components_): 
            if metric(x_new, x_core) < dbscan_model.eps:
                # Assign label of x_core to x_new
                y_new[j] = dbscan_model.labels_[dbscan_model.core_sample_indices_[i]]
                break

    return y_new

def my_custom_function(model, X, y=None):
    # for models that implement it, e.g. KMeans, could use `predict` instead
    preds = dbscan_predict(model, X)
    return silhouette_score(X, preds) if len(set(preds)) > 1 else float('nan')

model = DBSCAN()
pgrid = {
    'eps': [0.1*i for i in range(1,8)],
    'min_samples': range(2,5)
}

Z, _ = make_blobs(400, random_state=0)
gs = GridSearchCV(model, pgrid, scoring=my_custom_function)
gs.fit(Z)
best_estimator = gs.best_estimator_
best_score = gs.score(Z)
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35458920/5025009

Comment: Happy to help more. `dbscan_model.labels_` is the labels for each point in the dataset given to `fit` method. `dbscan_model.components_` are the core sample found by training and these are the most "stable" points per cluster discovered. `len(db.labels_)` is equal to the number of samples and `len(dbscan_model.core_sample_indices_)` is equal to the number of CORE points

Comment: please read how the algo works and it will all make sense https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN